# How to replace blank lines by newline character?

Tags: line-breaking, pdfcomment

I would like to replace blank lines in a command by the newline character `\textCR`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\mypdfcomment[2][]{\pdfcomment[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
  \mypdfcomment{first line

  second line}
\end{document}
```

Here I would like

```
\mypdfcomment{first line

  second line}
```

to produce

```
\pdfcomment{first line\textCR second line}
```

Background: `pdfcomment` does not understand blank lines and instead uses `\textCR`. It would be good not having to care about.

Comment: Please make a complete example, including the definition of `\mypdfcomment`

Comment: @egreg The idea was just to have `\mypdfcomment` do the same as `\pdfcomment` except for the replacement of the empty lines. Maybe you know what is going wrong in trying to use the solution below to replace `\newline` and `\\` as well (see comments)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\newcommand\mypdfcomment[2][]{{%
    \let\par\textCR
    \pdfcomment[#1]{#2}%
  }}

\begin{document}
  \mypdfcomment{first line

  second line}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And my limited LaTeX knowledge was enough to recover the optional argument. So I am using `\newcommand{\mypdfcomment}[2][]{\bgroup
  \let\par\textCR
  \pdfcomment[#1]{#2}\egroup}`. Is there a particular reason you introduced the `domypdfcomment`? Or was it just to make the code clearer?

Comment: I realised that there are a couple of additional line breaks in LaTeX to take care of. I tried to include them like this: `\newcommand{\mypdfcomment}[2][]{\bgroup \let\par\textCR \let\newline\textCR \let\\\textCR \pdfcomment[#1]{#2}\egroup}`. But it doesn't work. Any idea on this?

Comment: @Daniel No idea why this does not work.  I edited my answer to reflect your desired solution.  The two-stage macro was a leftover from a previous attempt, I removed it.

Comment: My guess is that it does not work because `\pdfcomment` already removes the `\newline` somehow. Notice that a blank line in `\pdfcomment` leads to en error while `\newline` does not and makes no change.