# How to replace tab by other command?

Tags: spacing

It is possible to replace empty lines by using `\let\par\mycommand`. Is there a way to do the same with tabs? I tried `\let\>\mycommand` but it didn't work.

(I am using it in order to replace those commands within comments from the pdfcomment package, see [How to replace blank lines by newline character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330938/36836).)

**Edit**

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\newcommand\mypdfcomment[2][]{{%
    \let\>\textHT
    \pdfcomment[#1]{#2}%
  }}

\begin{document}
  \mypdfcomment{before<tab>after}
\end{document}
```

Where `<tab>` is a real tab stop inserted via the keyboard. (Unfortunately, stackexchange seems not to allow real tab stops in code.)

Comment: Are you asking how redefine tabstops of the tabbing environment or actual tab characters `\t` in your file?

Comment: @siracusa Thanks. I want to redefine actual tabs in my file. I just tried `\let\t\mycommand` but it did not work.

Comment: @siracusa I've added an example. Maybe it becomes clearer what I am after then.

Comment: When one of your ”empty lines“ will actually contain a TAB character, you'll regret this  redefinition of it.

Comment: @Daniel I mean *outside* the `\pdfcomment` command

Comment: @egreg Oh I see. Yes, the restriction of the replacement to the `\pdfcomment` is still unsolved. I wrote that in a comment to the answer but flagged it now in my question as well. Unfortunately, I did not realize when posting my question that the command for replacing tabs is so different from the one for 'empty lines'.

Comment: @egreg And it seems that just putting it inside the `\renewcommand` which seems like the obvious answer doesn't work.

Comment: Of course not. So long as you're *totally, absolutely, downright all the way sure* that TABs will not sneak in your typescript except in the argument to `\pdfcomment`, siracusa's solution is good. Why do you want to shoot at your own foot? `;-)` Besides, what are you going to do if a TAB only produces a single visible space on the screen? How do you distinguish the TAB from a space?

Comment: @egreg I don't know why moving siracusa's command did not work. And I am *absolutely not sure* that there will be no tabs outside. That is why I prefer to limit the replacement to the `\pdfcomment`. Maybe Heiko's answer does that? I just can't get it to work at all with the replacement of the empty lines. You see my dilemma. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Okay, overlooked the updates the others made. That might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The category code of the tab character can be changes. For example, it can be made active and defined as macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\newcommand*\mypdfcomment[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=9\relax
  \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
    \def~%
  }{\textHT}%
  \catcode9=\active
  \mypdfcommentAux{#1}%
}
\newcommand\mypdfcommentAux[2]{%
  \let\par\textCR
  \pdfcomment[{#1}]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \mypdfcomment{%
    before  after

    new line%
  }
\end{document}
```

If you just want to retain the horizontal tab in the comment, then it can be set to category code 12 (other) like digits and punctuation characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\newcommand*\mypdfcomment[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode9=12\relax
  \mypdfcommentAux{#1}%
}
\newcommand\mypdfcommentAux[2]{%
  \let\par\textCR
  \pdfcomment[{#1}]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \mypdfcomment{%
    before      after

    new line%
  }
\end{document}
```

In both cases, the space between `before` and `after` is the horizontal tabulator (character code 9).

Category changes do not work, if `\mypdfcomment` with arguments is put into the argument of another macro.

**Update:** Support for empty lines inside comment text added.

Comment: Thanks. Where would I put the `\let\par\textCR` to replace empty lines in your example?

Comment: @Daniel The first example uses `\textHT`, replace it to your needs.

Comment: Ah, no I think that is a misunderstanding. I want to replace empty lines by `\textCR` in addition to the tabs by `\textHT` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330938/how-to-replace-blank-lines-by-newline-character).

Comment: @Daniel See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work perfect. Now I am wondering why the people who created the pdfcomment package haven't thought of this. At least it would have made my life easier. `:-)`

Comment: Why are there two `%`s in use of the `\mypdfcomment`? It seems I get an extra space before `before` if I remove them.

Comment: @Daniel TeX usually replace line ends by spaces. Therefore, you get spaces before `before` and after `new line` if the line ends are not commented (without percent).

Answer (score 3):

In the document's preamble, define

```
\catcode`\^^09=\active
\def^^09{\leavevmode\hskip2em}
```

`^^09` is the character with hexadecimal code 09 which (usually) is the tab character. So the first command makes that character "active", i.e. gives it category code 13, such that it can be used as a macro name.

The second command then defines a new macro with the tab character as the macro name (inserting an empty space of 2em width in this example). You could also directly use the tab character instead of `^^09`, but it's more difficult to read, IMHO.

Whenever you use the tab character in your document then, TeX will treat it as a macro and expand it just as it does with the "normal" macro names starting with `\`.

Comment: I managed to get your code working (see the edit in my question). Please let me know what you think. Is there a way to make the tab be replaced only within the redefined `\pdfcomment`?

Comment: If you only want to enable it in a certain command only, you have to carefully time the catcodes changes. This is exactly what Heiko does in his answer, which is why I would suggest to accept his answer instead.